# What does this sequence converge of recursive logarithms to?

Tags: convergence-divergence, logarithms, cauchy-sequences

Does anyone know what this sequence converges to?

$t_1 = \ln(n)$

$t_2 = \ln(n - t1) = \ln(n - \ln(n))$

$t_3 = \ln(n - t2) = \ln(n - \ln(n - \ln(n)))$

$...$

$t_k = \ln(n - t_{k-1})$

Notice that $t_1 < t_2$, $t_2 > t_3$, $t_3 < t_4$, ... and that $|t_k - t_{k+1}| \to 0$

Comment: If the sequence has a limit $x$, then it must hold that $x=\ln(n-x)$, which implies $e^x+x=n$.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Gerhard S. commented, then you need to solve for $x$ the equation $e^x+x=n$, the solution of which being given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$x=n-W(e^n)$$

Assuming $n$ to be "large", a very good approximation is given by $$x=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) \log (n)$$ For $n=10$, the "exact" value would be $\approx 2.07058$ while the approximation gives $\approx 2.07233$.

Comment: Well done ! Chers !

Answer (score 0):

In the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function , page 13, §."Relationship with the Lambert W function", one can found an expansion in infinite series which corresponds to your sequence.

The notations $x$ in the paper and $n$ in your question are related as :
 $$n=\ln(x)$$

The condition of convergence given in the paper is $\quad x\geq e\quad$ thus, corresponding to $n\geq 1$.

Putting $x=e^n$ into the series given in the paper :
$\quad\to\quad W(e^n)=n-t_\infty (n)$
$$t_\infty (n)=n-W(e^n)$$
This is consistent with Claude Leibovici's result.

Comment: Where does my question originate?  It started with an inequality: $\theta < log_2(n-\theta-1)$, from which I get $\theta < log_2(n - \theta)$.   Although I guess the question is just as interesting for any base of the logarithm.  What I'd like is the most restrictive bound on $\theta$.   So perhaps what I really want is the minimum, value of $t_i$, not necessarily the limit since the sequence is not monotonic.

If my intuition is correct, for large $n$, the minimum value of $\{t_i\}_i^\infty$ is $t_2$, for that's where the argument of ln is smallest.